# How to get nested error messages with Symfony Validator?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-validator

I am trying to validate raw values like described in the Symfony docs.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/raw_values.html

When I provide the `name` key in the input - I see nested errors. But when I do not provide it - validation stops on the parent field.
In other words, I want to run nested validation always, even if the parent field is missed.

Expected response when parent key is missed:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["path"]=>
    string(18) "[name][first_name]"
    ["message"]=>
    string(22) "This field is missing."
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["path"]=>
    string(17) "[name][last_name]"
    ["message"]=>
    string(22) "This field is missing."
  }
}
```

Real response (when parent key is missed):

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["path"]=>
    string(6) "[name]"
    ["message"]=>
    string(22) "This field is missing."
  }
}
```

Uncomment the `name` field in the `$input` to reproduce the behavior.

Code:

```
<?php

require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;

$validator = Validation::createValidator();

$input = [
    //'name' => [],
];

$constraint = new Assert\Collection(
    [
        'name' => new Assert\Collection(
            [
                'first_name' => new Assert\Required(),
                'last_name' => new Assert\Required(),
            ],
        ),
    ]
);

$items = [];

$violations = $validator->validate($input, $constraint);
foreach ($violations as $violation) {
    $items[] = [
        'path' => $violation->getPropertyPath(),
        'message' => $violation->getMessage(),
    ];
}

var_dump($items);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to check for the parent key then use an appropriately different `Assert\Collection` object for the structure of the input.

```php
<?php

require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;

$validator = Validation::createValidator();

$input = [
    //'name' => [],
];

$notNestedConstraint = new Assert\Collection(
    [
        'first_name' => new Assert\Required(),
        'last_name' => new Assert\Required(),
    ],
);
$nestedConstraint = new Assert\Collection(
    [
        'name' => $notNestedConstraint,
    ]
);

$items = [];
$constraint = (array_key_exists('name', $input)) ? $nestedConstraint: $notNestedConstraint

$violations = $validator->validate($input, $constraint);
foreach ($violations as $violation) {
    $items[] = [
        'path' => $violation->getPropertyPath(),
        'message' => $violation->getMessage(),
    ];
}

var_dump($items);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this doesn't seem like a solution for me. I hoped for some parameter that allows running nested rules

Comment: The structure of your constraint requires a collection under the `'name'` key if it is missing there is no point in validating the contents which also do not exist, so the collection validation supersedes nested validation. If the collection is not there, then it obviously will not have the child elements, it would be redundant for the validator to continue validating beyond that point.